# What is the function of "such as" in this sentence?

Tags: terminology

> You should take an AP class, **such as** U.S. History or English Literature.
>
> Many countries, **such as** Canada, New Zealand, and Switzerland, have more than one official language.

In a sentence where *such as* is used to precede a list of examples, what function does the *such as* serve? It seems sort of like a conjunction because it links together two parts of the sentence, but it is not included on any lists of conjunctions I have found.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As with its close cousin *[like](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/like_1)*, *such as* functions as a *preposition*, showing the relation of the nouns or pronouns that follow it to the phrase that precedes it.

The main the difference between *like* and *such as*, as summarized by [this column](http://www.quickanddirtytips.com/education/grammar/like-versus-such-as), is that *like* implies *comparison*, while *such as* implies *inclusion*.

Comment: The examples would mean the same thing if *for example* replaced *such as*. That is a long way from inclusion.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that it is a preposition instead of a conjunction.  "Such as" usually precedes a list of nouns and expresses a relation to another word/aspect of the clause.

So in your example, "such as" expresses a relation between the list of nouns ("Canada, New Zealand, and Switzerland") and the "Many countries."  It modifies "Many countries."

The end of the first paragraph [HERE](http://grammar.ccc.commnet.edu/grammar/prepositions.htm) was helpful.

Answer (score -1):

In both of your examples the phrase 'such as' means the same thing as 'for example'. It is not a conjunction but is probably a [conjunctive adverb](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjunctive_adverb).

Comment: But conjunctive adverbs join independent clauses. "Such as" isn't joining independent clauses; it's just connecting words or phrases to the rest of the sentence.